# Four fours to get any number

Tags: python, algorithm, programming-challenge

I decided to solve a problem from Code Golf called **the four fours**.

Problem description:

> The Four fours puzzle is a popular recreational mathematical puzzle
> that involves using exactly four 4s (and no other number) and a
> defined set of operations to reach every number from 0 to a given
> maximum.
>
> In this version, the only following operators are allowed:
>
> - Any grouping symbols may be used
> - Addition (+), Subtraction (-), Multiplication (*), Division (/)
> - Factorial (!), Gamma function (Γ)
> - Exponentiation (^), Square root (√)
>   *Concatenation (eg. 44 is two 4s)
>   Decimal point (eg. 4.4 is two 4s), Overbar (eg. .4~ = 4/9)

Some assumption/changes I made:

- I assumed that squaring a number is ok (using 4**2 or 16)
- I assumed that decimal values, in the cases where they occur can be truncated (4.9 = 4)

### Description of the algorithm

First I create a list of all the possible start values, that is:

- The number itself
- The number squared
- The sqrt of the number
- The factorial of the number
- The gamma function of the number (factorial(number -1))

Then I iterate throu them with the `random_reduce` function that 'reduces' the list by applying each time a random function.

The function takes about 2 secons for all numbers upto a 100, finding a way to create all the numbers along the way.

I am looking for code-style advice and maybe a better algorithm suggestion.

```
from __future__ import division

import random
import operator as op
import math

def get_starts(lst,n):
    sqrt,power,fact,gamma = int(n**0.5),n**2,math.factorial(n),math.factorial(n-1) 
    return ( [a,b,c,d] for a in (sqrt,n,power,fact,gamma) \
             for b in (sqrt,n,power,fact,gamma) for c in (sqrt,n,power,fact,gamma) \
             for d in (sqrt,n,power,fact,gamma))

def random_reduce(lst,functions):
    functions_used = []
    result = lst[0]
    for i in lst[1:]:
        fun = random.choice(functions)
        functions_used.append(fun)
        result = fun(result,i)
    return result,[i.__name__ for i in functions_used]

def how_to_obtain(n,lst,functions):
    for i in range(500):
        for l in get_starts(lst,4):
            result = random_reduce(l,functions)
            if n == result[0]:
                return n,[l,result[1]]

def concat(a,b):
    return int(str(a) + str(b))

def div(a,b):
    return a // b

def solve_44(max_):
    numbers_solutions = {}
    for i in range(max_):
        numbers_solutions[i] = how_to_obtain(i,[4,4,4,4],[concat, op.add, op.mul, op.sub,
                                         div, op.pow, op.mod])

    return numbers_solutions

def ratio_of_Nones_in_dictionary(dict_):
    return (len({i:dict_[i] for i in dict_ if dict_[i] == None}) / len(dict_))
    
def main(max_):
    solution = solve_44(max_)
    for i in solution:
        print(solution[i])
    print("The random search failed to find a solution {}% of the times.".format(
        ratio_of_Nones_in_dictionary(solution)*100))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(100)
```

Answer (score 5):

> I am looking for code-style advice and maybe a better algorithm suggestion.

As for coding style, first and foremost, please follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

#### Simplify

You could simplify `get_starts` using `product` from `itertools`:

```
def get_starts(n):
    sqrt, power, fact, gamma = int(n ** 0.5), n ** 2, math.factorial(n), math.factorial(n - 1)
    return product((sqrt, n, power, fact, gamma), repeat=4)
```

I also dropped the unused `lst` parameter.
In fact many of the functions have unused parameters,
remove them everywhere.

#### Use generators, they are awesome

Since you accumulate solutions in an array,
the program seems to freeze for a few seconds while calculating,
rather than printing the solutions that are ready.
You could improve that by using a *generator* instead, for example:

```
def solve_44(max_):
    for i in range(max_):
        yield how_to_obtain(i, [concat, op.add, op.mul, op.sub, div, op.pow, op.mod])


def main(max_):
    none_count = 0
    for solution in solve_44(max_):
        print(solution)
        if solution is None:
            none_count += 1
    print("The random search failed to find a solution {}% of the times.".format(
        none_count / max_ * 100))
```

Another correction here is using `is None` instead of `== None` for comparing with `None` values.

Answer (score 4):

As a rule, doing maths is quicker than playing with strings. In this case, a bit of testing suggests that mixing the two gives the best performance. You can speed up your `concat` operation by a factor of 2 on that basis:

```
>>> import math
>>> def concat_strings(a, b):
    """Original version, converts both numbers to strings and back."""
    return int(str(a) + str(b))

>>> def do_maths(a, b):
    """Pure mathematical version."""
    return b + (a * (10 ** (int(math.log(b, 10)) + 1)))

>>> def combined(a, b):
    """Pragmatic version; avoid relatively slow library call."""
    return b + (a * (10 ** len(str(b))))

>>> tests = [(1, 2), (12, 3), (1, 23), (1, 234), (12, 34), (123, 4)]
>>> for t in tests:
    assert concat_strings(*t) == do_maths(*t) == combined(*t)


>>> import timeit
>>> setup = "from __main__ import tests, concat_strings, do_maths, combined"
>>> for method in ['concat_strings', 'do_maths', 'combined']:
    print method,
    timeit.timeit("for t in tests: {}(*t)".format(method), setup=setup)


concat_strings
10.974838972091675
do_maths
6.453880071640015
combined
4.8371992111206055
```

Also, note that your `div` function is available as [`operator.floordiv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.floordiv).